# Would detonating a powerful nuke on the Moon really cause a Richter 7 moonquake? Do we know enough about the moon to predict this?

Tags: the-moon, impact

A recent [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEfPBt9dU60) of Kurzgesagt explores the consequences of exploding a hydrogen bomb on/near the surface of the moon. At [3:48](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEfPBt9dU60&t=228) they consider the resulting moonquake, saying it's comparable to a magnitude 7 (Richter scale) earthquake.

While the rest of the episode is awesome-but-predictable, this caught me off-guard. Do we really know all that much about the internal structure of the Moon, so that predictions like this can be furnished? Isn't it possible that the internal structure has voids which could lead to resonance, which can make the quake much worse? I know we have seismometers on the moon and have used upper stages of rockets as deliberate impactors to calibrate them - but these are far less energetic collisions. Have we ever measured something massive impacting the Moon, setting off similar (Richter 7 or more) quake?

### Recap (questions)

1. Have we ever recorded a Richter 7 or more moonquake (from known or unknown causes)?
2. If not, is it reasonable to extrapolate from less-energetic deliberate collisions?

Comment: one question per question

Comment: sorry, I know the rule. I just thought they are very related.

Comment: Kind of depends on just how close the seismometer is to the explosion...

Comment: Not sure where to find info about the effects of nuclear weapons in space, but most of the destruction caused by nuclear explosions near the surface of the Earth is due to the sudden expansion of the huge volume of air (up to several cubic miles of it) that is heated by radiation from the bomb. There's no air on the Moon. If a nuke were exploded on or above the Lunar surface, I would not expect much of a "blast." OTOH, the effect of a _buried_ nuke should be comparable to the effects of the many underground tests that have been done here on Earth.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, yes, the explosion is very different from what's in Earth atmosphere. Be sure to watch the video if you haven't, it's discussed in detail there. They don't discuss much why moon quakes are more easily caused beyond "since the moon is much smaller". There should be more to that.

Comment: `+1` and somewhat related in Earth Science SE: [What are the distinguishing features of an “artificial seismic wave” (e.g. a large underground explosion)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/12213/6031) There are plenty of questions about Mars and the Moon there. I think a question requiring seismic expertise is more likely to get a good answer there than here. So while this is on-topic here, you might consider flagging for moderator help to migrate this there if you don't receive adequate answers here.